# Change canvas size without cropping in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, crop, canvas

It is possible to have images and objects, which are larger than canvas size in photoshop:

[image]

Then why is it asking for crop if canvas resized?

[image]

Why should I loose information when I resizing just a canvas?

Is it possible to keep data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to change the size without loosing pixels you actually have to use the crop tool but deselect the "delete cropped pixels" box:
[image]

Comment: This is a F$%& answer from 2015 how I didn't see this after 10 years of using Adobes products lol... Thank girl!!!.... I allways had everything cropped lol

Answer (score 0):

You need the duplicate the layer before do the canvas crop.
Because background doesn't preserve the image.

Comment: Why? How can one get it?  Please explain better what to do, maybe with adding an screenshot?  Suppose the reader does not know all what you know.  A valid answer should be understandable by its own ... Welcome to GD.SE!